# How to reproduce exception when performing DELETE query in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, exception, sql-delete

I want to reproduce an exception when performing a DELETE query from a table in Oracle database for some tests.

But how to make an exception occurs when deleting?

Comment: You need to first understand **run time** vs **compile time** errors. PL/SQL exception block will catch the run time errors and not the compile time errors.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, but i already know that. My question is how to **make an exception occurs** (how many way?) when perform a DELETE query, not how to handle the exception.

Comment: Are you asking all the possibilities of an error out of a DELETE statement?

Comment: The answer would depend on what exception it is you want to occur. If you want a delete by zero exception, include `where 1/0 = 1` in the query. I assume it is some other exception(s) you want to force.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance Yeah, normally that DELETE query should run just fine, i just think that maybe locking that TABLE would force an exception but dont know how to do that yet.

Comment: Apart from just raising an exception in an ON DELETE trigger, another way would be to add a foreign key constraint on another table pointing at your table (with no cascade on delete) so that deletes will fail with an exception.

Answer (score 0):

> But how to make an exception occurs when deleting?

Remember, **PL/SQL exception block** will catch the **run time** errors and not the **compile time** errors.

First execute the code without any exception block, thus you will get the entire error stack with exact line numbers.

Based on the complete error stack, if you want to gracefully handle the exceptions, then create your **user-defined exception** and handle them in the **EXCEPTION** block.

For example,

**Without exception block**

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2    DELETE FROM emp WHERE loc = 'NEW_YORK';
  3  END;
  4  /
  DELETE FROM emp WHERE loc = 'NEW_YORK';
                        *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 25:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "LOC": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

So, I could see **ORA-00904 Invalid Identifier** error in the error stack.

**Handle exception**

```
SQL> SET serveroutput ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2    invalid_identifier EXCEPTION;
  3    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(invalid_identifier, -904);
  4    text VARCHAR2(128);
  5  BEGIN
  6    text:='DELETE FROM emp WHERE loc = ''NEW_YORK''';
  7    EXECUTE immediate text;
  8  EXCEPTION
  9  WHEN invalid_identifier THEN
 10    dbms_output.put_line('Invalid identifier error in delete statement');
 11  END;
 12  /
Invalid identifier error in delete statement

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

DBMS_OUTPUT was only for demonstration purpose, in reality you would be logging the errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a condition based on which you would want to raise an exception pertaining to the business logic. However, if you want to forcefully raise an exception, you can define your exception and raise it like 'raise your_exception';

Answer (score 0):

```
create table test_delete(a varchar2(10));
    insert into test_delete values('abc');
    insert into test_delete values('abc');
    insert into test_delete values('err123');
    insert into test_delete values('err3');

    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER delete_exeption
     BEFORE
      DELETE
     ON test_delete
    REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
     FOR EACH ROW
    begin 

     if( INSTR( :old.a, 'err') > 0 ) then
       raise_application_error(-20000,'Error');
     end if;
    end;
    /


    delete from test_delete where a = 'abc'; -- no error
    delete from test_delete where a = 'err123'; -- error
```

Error will occur only during delete rows contains "err" in column a

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you seek for the semantics of exceptions.
Here's an example:

```
DECLARE
   pe_ratio NUMBER(3,1);
BEGIN
   SELECT price / earnings INTO pe_ratio FROM stocks
     WHERE symbol = 'XYZ';  -- might cause division-by-zero error
     INSERT INTO stats (symbol, ratio) VALUES ('XYZ', pe_ratio);
   COMMIT;
   EXCEPTION  -- exception handlers begin
   WHEN ZERO_DIVIDE THEN  -- handles 'division by zero' error
   INSERT INTO stats (symbol, ratio) VALUES ('XYZ', NULL);
   COMMIT;
   ...
  WHEN OTHERS THEN  -- handles all other errors
  ROLLBACK;
END;  -- exception handlers and block end here
```

As you can see, you can use predefined exceptions or use the 'WHEN OTHER THEN' clause for others, in fact you can use it for all you exceptions.
Actually I copied this example from Oracle documentations from the link below, here you can find the list of predefined exceptions as well:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/07_errs.htm